# How to correct SQL Server Import and Export Wizard error that says my data conversion length must be between 0 and 4000?

Tags: import, azure-sql-database, excel

The message I get from the 2017 SQL Server Import and Export Wizard which I need help with is,

> "Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The 'Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Description]' has a
>   length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 4000"

The data source column in question is titled "Description" and is of Excel type "General". This spreadsheet was given a long filename extension of ".iqy.xslx", and it was produced by a SharePoint Online's "Export to Excel" command which I performed on a SharePoint list. I'm using Excel installed locally via the Office365 website. Back in the SharePoint list, the original column "Description" is of type "Multiple lines of text". The destination I am trying to populate using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard is a VARCHAR(MAX) column within a table inside an Azure SQL Database.

[image: Mapping an Excel source to an Azure destination field in my SQL DB]

You can clearly see in the following screen how the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard perceives the Excel data column in question. Here it calls it a "LongText", and I'm unable to change the data types of neither the source nor the destination:

[image: Data source and destination types]

The error message pops up once I begin the conversion in a subsequent screen, and you can see it if you click on the Messages link as seen below.

[image: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Error]

How can I properly input this simple Excel spreadsheet into my table on Azure?

Comment: try to change source column's type to varchar(MAX)

Comment: I do not see a way to do that. I've added a little more information on what options I do see available. It seems the source column's data type is not negotiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally obtained an easy enough workaround. What I did was reopen my *.idy.xlsx Excel spreadsheet where my source data resided and re-saved it as an Excel 97-2003 Workbook.  These get a filename extension of *.xls. I went back to the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard and repeated the import steps, this time selecting the newly saved *.xls file. Ladies and gentlemen, it worked. A pair of trivial warnings appeared but the data came through flawlessly for me!

[image]